# MySQL Specific Query Requirement

Tags: datetime, mysql

I have datetime field names "salestime" in "sales" table

I need to get data as:

```
SalesMonthYear      Total
2010-11             10
2010-10             15
2010-09             21
```

or

```
Nov-2010            10
Oct-2010            15
Sep-2010            21
```

Any one know how can I achieve this using query?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(salesTime, '%Y-%m') AS salesMonthYear,
       COUNT(*) AS salesCount
FROM sales
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(salesTime, '%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and `GROUP BY` to achieve what you want. This query will do it:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(salestime, '%Y-%m') as SalesMonthYear, count(*) as `Total` FROM `sales` GROUP BY SalesMonthYear ORDER BY `salestime`
```

And for the second version:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(salestime, '%b-%Y') as SalesMonthYear, count(*) as `Total` FROM `sales` GROUP BY SalesMonthYear ORDER BY `salestime`
```

Comment: thanks, but I think DATE_FORMAT(`salestime`,'%Y-%m') and not in the way as you mention

Comment: Ohh yes, I screwed that one in hurry.